# Bypassing valid certificate requirement for websockets

Tags: javascript, websocket

I'm attempting to connect to a websocket server hosted in C# using SuperWebSockets from a page. The issue is that the websocket server generates a self-signed certificate making it difficult to connect to from the browser. The ServerConfig of the SuperWebSocket has "tls" for Security and passes on a self-signed certificate filepath through the Certificate member of the ServerConfig.

I was wondering if anyone knew any hacky tricks to connect to this web socket server from a web page, I'm open to ideas for either/both Firefox or Chrome. I know there are ways to do this if the user adds an exception for the certificate or disables certificate validation, but I need a method that's pure javascript. Perhaps emulating TLS?

Comment: It would help to help you if you can tell us whether you are hosting the server or just a consumer?

Comment: @fossil I'm pentesting a piece of software which hosts it on my local machine.

Comment: You can consider creating your own certificate authority and create a server certificate for your server and add the CA certificate as trusted CA to your browsers. You can consider using a tool like https://sourceforge.net/projects/xca/ for managing your certificates.

Comment: If having your own certificate works for you I can write an answer with detailed instructions.

Comment: @fossil I cannot specify my own certificate. This software generates a new one on start everytime, I have no control over it. I am trying to see if it's possible to create an html page which can communicate with the software without user interaction, issue being that the websocket server has an invalid certificate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to disable certificate validation or accept an invalid or self-signed certificate using pure Javascript in the browser. And it would be a very bad idea if something like this exists since it might enable attackers to man in the middle critical sites when you've visited the attackers site.

You might explicitly import the certificate as trusted in each browser or you might offer access to this site by HTTPS (i.e. not only `wss://`) so that the user can create an explicit exception for this site. But this can thankfully not be automated, i.e. it requires explicit user interaction.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually fairly easy to bypass certificates for development, without having to add them to the certificate trust store.

If you attempt to load an HTTPS webpage with an untrusted certificate chrome allows you to ignore the error (either by clicking `advanced`, then `proceed to ...`, OR if they are using HSTS, by typing `thisisunsafe`). This automatically applies to any websocket connections the site makes to the same domain.

This means if you host the entire site, proxying all calls to the original domain (except for the websocket connection), you can easily ignore the security warning and the websocket should work fine.

Comment: Welcome to the community. OP specifically asks for Websockets security bypass in the browser..

Comment: Yep, this technique would only work in the browser (chrome specifically). They also mention having a backend, hosted in C#, using SuperWebSockets, so I presumably they have the ability to host the site as well (they will need to for this to work).

Comment: Oh you're right, sorry, I must've misread.